# Удаление кнопки

Tags: javascript

У меня есть кнопка "Добавить в друзья". После того, как нажать эту кнопку, нужно чтобы она исчезла. Как это сделать?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне удалить кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

`element.remove()`
например для этого сайта, убираем кнопку share/vkontakte  после клика:

```
element=document.getElementsByClassName('share')[0].children[0]
element.addEventListener('click',function() {this.remove()});
```